# Блуд и блуждать

Tags: однокоренные-слова

Интересно, "блуждать" — ходить где-то, не находя выхода (блуждать в лабиринте), а блуд — разврат. Прочему один и тот же корень для совершенно разных понятий?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Изначальное значение -- *сбиваться с правильного пути*.

Иногда и сейчас, во всяком случае на Украине, в этом смысле употребляют слово *"блудить"*. Бродить без пути.

Беспутная девка -- ведущая себя *неправильно*. А в традиционных обществах, т.е. обществах где поведение основано на традициях, а не на моде, обычно очень чёткие представления, как правильно себя вести в жизненных ситуациях.

Вот например слово "грех". Есть слово "погрешность" -- значит "неточность". А грех -- это промах. :-) "Случилась промашка ужасная", как говорил Глеб Жеглов. Человек поступил **неправильно** и получил за это от судьбы. Не по **ПРАВДЕ**, говоря по старинному. Неправедно. Наступил на грабли, и получил по лбу. При этом незнание закона не освобождает от ответственности.

Есть слово "распутица". Когда пути-дороги пропадают. И есть слово "распутная", когда женщина отходит от традиционного для женщины поведения. Пути с большой буквы, как говорят в Китае и Японии. Какие традиционные для женщины ценности? Архетипы, так сказать. То что в ней самой от природы заложено. Хороший брак, хорошая семья, уютный дом и дети. Быть **за мужем**.

*Отклонения* от этой модели вы, наверное, видели. Пьянки-гулянки, бардак дома, смены/измены мужского пола. Типа свободная женщина в свободном поиске. Только, гарантирую, гадко у неё на душе от такой жизни. И очень скоро это отражается на внешности. **Портит** это женщину. Вот ещё один важный смысл греха и блуда.

Comment: последний абзац-то зачем добавили? наболело?